# make jQuery table sorter sort in ascending order everytime a new column is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to ask if there's a way to make table sorter sort in ascending order everytime a new column is clicked?

thanks!

Comment: better add link to jquery plugin also.

Comment: pretty sure there's a way. please show us some of your code

Comment: So far, I looked at this [link](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). The problem with that is it remembers the last sorting order per column. What i would want to accomplish is to make a column to sort in ASC order everytime it is clicked the first time e.g. ColumnA to be sorted ASC and i clicked ColumnB which will be sorted in ASC, then back to ColumnA which will be sorted in ASC order (and not DESC). Thanks for the help. =)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the columns to only sort by their initial sort direction, find and comment out this line in jquery.tablesorter.js:

```
this.order = this.count++ % 2;
```

This is the line which updates the column to sort in the opposite direction the next time the header is clicked. Commenting this out means that the sort order will always be the same. But it also means that you won't be able to sort in the opposite direction.

I had a situation (which may be the same as you described) where I wanted each column to sort in the initial sort direction the first time I clicked, but still wanted to be able to sort the other direction when I clicked again. eg. Clicking Column A would sort ASC, then clicking again would sort DESC then again ASC. Clicking B would sort ASC, then clicking A again would sort ASC. With the original tablesorter code, that last sort would be DESC, since the Column A sort of the previous click was ASC.

Here is how I solved that. It may be kludgy and clumsy, but it works for me.

In the buildHeaders function, find this line:

`this.order = formatSortingOrder( checkHeaderOrder(table, index) );`

and add this after it:

`this.initialOrder = formatSortingOrder( checkHeaderOrder(table, index) );`

Replace the line I mentioned earlier:

`this.order = this.count++ % 2;`

With this:

```
if($lastColumn == i){
    this.order = ++this.count % 2;
}else{
    this.order = this.initialOrder;
}
$lastColumn = i;
```

Now, say Column A's sortInitialOrder was ASC and B was DESC. The following would happen:

1. Click A: Sorts A ASC
2. Click B: Sorts B DESC
3. Click B: Sorts B ASC
4. Click A: Sorts A ASC

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fork of tablesorter where you can pass a lockedOrder parameter: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers-locked.html